# Perl - Set up an array of hashes and access an item in a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

1. Are there any syntax errors in the setup of the array of hashes? It didn't give any warnings, but I also cannot print an item, so I hope that the setup isn't the problem.
2. How can I access eg `x` inside of `list5` to print it?

.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my (%list0, %list1, %list2, %list3, %list4, %list5);

%list5 = (
"list" => 5,
"x" => 1,
"y" => 1,
"z" => 0,
);

my @full_list = (%list0, %list1, %list2, %list3, %list4, %list5);

print ??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of an array of hashes (AoH) are [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) to those hashes, so you need to populate `@full_list` with hash references.  Given your script, do the following:

```
my @full_list = \( %list0, %list1, %list2, %list3, %list4, %list5 );
```

Then, to access "`x` inside of `list5`":

```
print $full_list[5]->{x}; # prints 1
```

The `->` notation is the [arrow operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator), which dereferences the hash reference in `$full_list[5]`.

To use `list5` as the index into `@full_list`, you can use the [constant pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use constant list5 => 5;

...

print $full_list[list5]->{x}; # prints 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible to alternatively index `full_list` using `list5` rather than numerical index `5`?

Comment: @Stuart - Yes, by using the `constant` pragma.  Have updated my answer to include it.

Comment: Thanks you have been very helpful! Last thing, how can I pull out a single list eg `my %temp = %full_list[5]`? So that I can use `$temp->{x}` to access items.

Comment: @Stuart - You're most welcome.  You're very close!  Just change the [sigil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29) from `%` to `$`: `my $temp = $full_list[list5]; print $temp->{x};`  Notice that it's as if `$temp` just takes `$full_list[list5]`'s place...

Comment: When you make `temp` a scalar, then how can it have all the information of a hash? 
I feel like I need a hash to use this loop:
`foreach my $key ( keys %temp ){
    print "key: $key, value: $temp->{$key}\n";
}`

Comment: *"I feel like I need a hash..."*  Again, you're very close.  Just do this: `keys %$temp` to dereference `$temp`.

Comment: Awesome, you rock! Is this something you automatically understand, or you figured it out through practice? I know basic C and pointers, but still get confused when dealing with dereferencing and moving between datatypes. Can you recommend a tutorial/documentation to help a relative beginner?

Comment: @Stuart - Thank you. No, nothing automatic at all.  As you've said, it's practice.  Also readings--and I'll some recommendations later, but have to rush off now...

Comment: Please don't hesitate to let me know if I should start a new question, but do you know if I can modify/access `full_list` in a way where I can use a `key` to access any item in the full list hash, while still keeping the hash lists arrayed like they currently are? Basically I want the separate lists for printing, but I would like a "master" list for indexing.

Comment: @Stuart - I don't think I can do better than [this node at PerlMonks](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1049875) for Perl resources.  Also, studying how other's solve posted questions has helped immensely.

Comment: @Stuart - If I understand your question correctly, you access the full array of hashes by: `$full_list[n]->{key}`, where n is a value from `0 .. $#full_list` (or use the `constant` pragma).  So you could `$full_list[list2]->{foo} = 'bar'` or `print $full_list[list4]->{bar};`.  Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: I meant, can we access `full_list` (ie `%whole_full_list = %full_list[0 .. $#full_list]`) without indexing into it with the partial list numbers, such that we can read/write `$whole_full_list->{x}`? It would be helpful to point to the key/value pairs in both ways at the same time. In other words, `full_list` and `whole_full_list` would ideally point to the same memory. I would like to use `whole_full_list` first for setting the values, and `full_list` for printout.

Comment: @Stuart - Not that I'm aware of.  Rather, something like `$full_list[$_]->{x} = 'Hello, world!' for 0 .. 5;`

Comment: next best would be to loop through each sublist and check if the key/value pair previously existed before modifying. Can we modify your slick one-liner to do this: `foreach (0..5){
 if($full_list[$_]->{x}){
  $full_list[$_]->{x} = 'Hello, world!'
 }
}`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48013/discussion-between-kenosis-and-stuart)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this is helpful:

As you have it defined (@full_list = (%list0, %list1,...);), the dump of the @full_list via

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@full_list;
```

looks like

```
$VAR1 = [
      'y',
      1,
      'x',
      1,
      'z',
      0,
      'list',
      5
    ];
```

where the even elements are your hash keys and the odd element following each is the value.  What Kenosis described is probably what you want.  But if for some reason, that is just given to you (in another form and you are simplifying it for us here) and you must work with @full_list or an array defined like that, you can get a hash back that consists of keys and values from all the initial hashes.

```
my %full_list_hash = @full_list;
print $full_list_hash{x};
```